# App engine does not store List when it is annotated with serializable and defaultFetchGroup set

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am trying to store an Jdo which has a List in it. When the list is annotated with

```
@Persistent (defaultFetchGroup = "true")
```

It works fine, but when I have

```
@Persistent (serializable = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
```

It does not store the list. Does anyone know why? What do I do when I have a list of custom objects that I want to store, do I mark them as serializable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 cases :

1. a core type (`List<String>`,`List<Date>`, etc...) : You should use `@Persistent`
2. a `@PersistenceCapable` class (`List<MyPersistenceCapableClass>`) : You should use `@Persistent`, it's the [One-To-Many relationship](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships) case
3. not a core type neither a `@PersistenceCapable` class but a `@Serializable` one (`List<MySerializableClass>`) : You **must** use `@Persistent (serializable = "true")`

When using `serializable = "true"`, you need to call `JDOHelper.makeDirty` to notify JDO **everytime** you modify the list :

```
MySerializableClass serializableObject = new MySerializableClass();
persistedObject.getMySerializableClassList().add(serializableObject);
JDOHelper.makeDirty(persistedObject, "mySerializableClassList");
```

***note*** : the `defaultFetchGroup = "true"` parameter is used to tell JDO to automatically fetch all objects of the list, and not wait for access to the field (lazy fetching).

Answer (score 1):

`@Persistent(serialized = "true", defaultFetchGroup="true")` is the correct annotation.

Also when you are changing something to an element of the list you should call `JDOHelper.makeDirty(this, "yourSerializedField");` because when it re-serialize the element it only looks at the reference not at each item (it uses .equals of the object)
Hope this helps